# F# SqlProvider library loading (Mono OS X)

Tags: .net, f#-interactive

I've been working with SqlProvider and FSharp.Data.Sql to access a local SQLite database, both in F# Interactive with an .fsx file, and in my compiled application. Getting System.Data.SQLite.dll to load properly, however, has been a challenge. I think this is a result of my not understanding .NET library loading properly, or maybe of not understanding the way F# type providers work, but it's difficult for me to research this topic because there's a lot of literature and I'm not sure where to start.

I've been mainly working in the .fsx file and sending the lines in the script to F# interactive. I had put System.Data.SQLite.dll in a lib/ directory in my assembly, and at the top of the script had

```
#I "lib"
#r "System.Data.SQLite.dll"
```

These two lines work fine when sent to F# Interactive -- it tells me that the proper directory has been added to the library include path, and that the .dll has been referenced. However, when I then try to create the type provider in FSI, I get a "Could not load file or assembly" error for the dll. When I move the library up into the root directory of my project, however, I no longer get this error, and am able to use the type provider.

When I compile the library, the System.Data.SQLite.dll file gets copied to the output folder along with the other dlls. However, the build also give me the "Could not load file or assembly" error and compilation fails.

To solve the problem in the .fsx file I had to add:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_PATH", "lib")
```

To solve the problem when compiling, I had to go into the Xamarin Studio preferences, and under Build > Assembly Folders add the lib directory to the "Custom folders where Xamarin Studio should look for assemblies and packages."

I am working in Xamarin Studio with Mono on OSX, but I get the impression that the problem is more general. System.Data.SQLite.dll is compiled for Mono, and as I mentioned, it works when I set the MONO_PATH.

My question is, why should I have to set the MONO_PATH? Why doesn't the #I directive for setting the library search directory cause the .dll to be loaded in F# Interactive (even after the #r directive says that the library has been loaded), and why doesn't the .dll being present in the build directory allow the type provider to use the .dll at compile time?

Comment: There is a clue on the SQLProvider [GitHub page](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/): "Database vendors other than MS SQL Server use dynamic assembly loading. This may cause some security problems depending on your system's configuration and which version of the .NET framework you are using. If you encounter problems loading dynamic assemblies, they can likely be resolved by applying the following element into the configuration files of fsi.exe, devenv.exe and your program or the program using your library : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(VS.100).aspx"

Comment: However, adding that configuration to the Xamarin Studio.exe.config didn't seem to change anything with regard to FSI's ability to load the dll without having it in the current working directory.